# My teleportation arrow has a broken angle

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok so I have a command block series that does these things in this order: Gives all arrows with a specific potion effect a custom name (EndArrow) > If it detects an arrow named "EndArrow" that is not in the ground, it sets all players in the "End" team to spectator mode > Repeatedly teleports all players on the "End" team to any arrows named "EndArrow" that aren't in the ground with a limit of 1 > If it detects an arrow named "EndArrow" that is in the ground, it sets all players in the "End" team to survival mode > It kills all arrows named "EndArrow" That gives me a nice "Arrow Cam" effect with a teleportation, but the camera angle is wrong while the arrow is flying.

After further research, I found another video with the same problem as me (

)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shooting the arrow in +z and -z directions works, but in +x and -x, the direction will flip. when tp-ing the player to the arrow, it inherits this odd behavior.

we can work around this by setting up command blocks like so:
[image]

the repeating command block on the left will tp the player to the arrow, without changing direction, like so:

```
/execute at <arrow> run tp <player> ~ ~ ~
```

then, a comparator leads out to a normal command block, that makes the player face the arrow:

```
/execute at @p run tp <player> ~ ~ ~ facing entity <arrow> eyes
```

for this one, the arrow will need to include the "limit=1" tag to work.

this is a smoother way to have the arrow perspective, and fixes the odd camera stuff.

Comment: You, my dear sir, are a genius. It didn't work originally, but I swapped the commands around and it worked perfectly (I also used a conditional chain command block, since that took up less space). Thank you so much fam

Comment: thanks! i noticed this issue 2 seconds after posting and facepalmed. glad it helped, though